# symfony: how to deal with two level linkage choice for entity type?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I'm using symfony. I have created a form with two entity types:

```
->add('Table', EntityType::class, array(
                'class'=>'AppBundle:TableList',
                'placeholder' => '',
                'choice_label'=>'tableName',))
->add('Field', EntityType::class, array(
                'class'=>'AppBundle:FieldList',
                'placeholder' => '',
                'choice_label'=>'fieldName',))
```

For both Table and Field, the form is in choice type, candidates are in the database. I want to ask how to deal with foreign key constraint? For example, if I have chosen 'Table1' in the first entity, then in the second entity, the choice candidates only show the fields of Table1 but not the fields of other tables.
Really want help how to achieve this two level linkage (sorry I'm not sure I'm telling this name appropriately)?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See Symfony docs - [Dynamic Generation for Submitted Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms). It is rather involved so don't expect a simple solution.

An alternative might be to create a 2-step form.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will look into the document!

Comment: hi shira, I read the document and follow the steps, but it doesn't work T_T. do you have time to help me a bit?

Comment: It might be a better idea just to post a new question, showing your code and describing your problems (including any error messages and such).